# How to merge two different number of rows table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have to insert a particular column from a new table(table 1) into my old table (table 2).

The tables looks as followed,

[image]
[image]

The number of rows of the tables is different, I would have to keep the number of rows in table 2, which means I need to plug in my the mean value from table 1 which ID and Duration match for both table.

I wrote a code like this

```
UPDATE [Table 2]    
SET [Mean] = [Table 1].[Mean]    
FROM         [Table 2]    
INNER JOIN   [Table 1]    
       ON    [Table 2].[ID] = [Table 1].[ID]
       AND   [Table 2].[Duration] = [Table 1].[Duration]
```

But the number of columns in Table 2 changed. What's wrong with my code and what is a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: An `update` statement can't change the number of columns in a table. I don't understand what you mean by that statement.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to update table 2 where id and duration match and otherwise insert them? (If yes, `merge` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) is a good option.)